# Unable to rotate iPhone to the right direction

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, rotation, xcode5

i've got this strange behavior from my iPhone device.
Hi built a view controller that can rotate from Left to Right landscape mode. Everything goes well in the simulator but when i build the project to the iPhone it always rotate to Left Landscape.

Here the two methods for the handling of the orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Is this some kind of accelerometer issue??

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you've locked the rotation on your iPhone ?

Comment: Replace your `UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight` with `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`

Comment: Thank you @spassas! Next time i'd read better what i write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Use this

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```